# A hierarchical kanban board

Tags: project-management, kanban

Are there any kanban boards that support hierarchy? And by hierarchy, I mean an ability to put a kanban board inside of a kanban board. I know Quire has something like this but it doesn't really work as expected

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear from your question why do you need such a structure. And as such, it is difficult to say which tool will answer your needs. But let me suggest one option that might work - [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/kanban/best-kanban-board-tools/).

This tool has a Kanban board that allows you to track both - the general process steps and additional process steps. For example, you can set up the board to have design, manufacturing, and testing columns. And then expand the design column with a subprocess that tracks tasks through a design process. Kind of a Kanban board inside of another Kanban board.

Alternatively, you could use several connected Kanban boards.

[image]